# Duda sobre varaibles estrictas de tipo Object en TypeScript

Tags: typescript, variables, operador, tipos

alguien sabe porque está linea de código no arroja error con el operador && en tiempo de compilación y de ejecución, y con los demás operadores como || === si lo arroja. Se supone que && devuelve un boolean y en esa linea de codigo estoy indicando que la variable debe ser tipo object, agradezco si alguien conoce la respuesta

```
let serie: object= "asd" && {nombre: "YOU"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si lo compilas como JS:

```
"use strict";
let serie = "asd" && { nombre: "YOU" };
```

Y si lo vuelcas a la consola:

```
console.log(serie);
```

Obtienes:

```
{ nombre: "YOU" }
```

Viendo la doc sobre [operadores lógicos en JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operadores_l%C3%B3gicos) aparece esto:

> AND Lógico (&&)   expr1 && expr2
> Devuelve expr1 si se puede convertir a false; de lo contrario, devuelve expr2. Por lo tanto, cuando se usa con valores booleanos, && devuelve true si ambos operandos son true; de lo contrario, devuelve false.

Y más abajo:

> Ejemplos de expresiones que se pueden convertir a false son aquellos que se evalúan como null, 0, NaN, la cadena vacía ("") o undefined.

Es decir que el string `"asd"` no se puede convertir a *false*, por lo que se le asigna el objeto a la derecha del operador `&&`.

Comment: Wow no conocía este concepto haciendo uso de &&, supongo que para los demás operadores lógicos debe suceder algo parecido en ciertos casos. Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: @Hugo, yo tampoco lo conocía. Cuando vi la doc lo primero que pensé es ¿cómo convierto un string en booleano directamente? siempre hago cosas como `(x !== '')`